# mime magic php enable

Tags: php

I understand mime_type is deprecated and should use fileinfo instead. My question is, do I still need to enable mime magic on php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the available, and somewhat lacking, documentation: No

Take a look at:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/fileinfo.requirements.php